# Why does my brake pedal go to the floor when i start the truck up?

Tags: ford, brakes, 4wd, f-250

My Ford F250 4x4 brake pedal goes to the floor when you start the truck and stay's to the floor until you shut the engine off then it returns? The brake booster, master cyl, rotors, pads, brake lines, drums, brake shoes, and brake cylinders have all been replaced.

Comment: Is the pedal firm when the truck isn't running?  Was the master cylinder bench-bled before installing, and are you sure everything was bled properly once installed (without more air entering the master)?

Comment: the pedal goes to the floor when the truck starts up. the pedal is firm when the truck is off.

Comment: Agree with @JPhi1618 line of thinking ... I'd bet the system needs to be properly bled.

Comment: Is it a diesel or gas? Does the brake booster run off a vacuum  pump?

Comment: Is there a way to get the booster valve that is stuck open free?

Answer (score 9):

One of the valves in the brake servo (booster) is stuck open.  When you start the engine the vacuum produced by the engine (or a separate vacuum pump) is used to assist braking pressure from your foot.  As you press the brake pedal, a valve in the servo opens to allow the vacuum to pull against the diaphragm in the servo to assist you.  If a valve is stuck open it will keep sucking until the pedal goes to the floor and will only release once the engine has stopped.

Presumably it is putting the brakes on when this happens.  If this is true, it is nothing to do with bleeding.

Depending on the design of the servo, there may be a pipe that connects the servo casing to the servo valve block, if this is leaking or missing, the same symptoms would occur.  Any air leak into the casing in the rear of the servo body will also produce these symptoms.

Comment: That's interesting.  Where is this Brake Servo located?  Is it a integrated part of the booster?

Comment: Sorry, you probably call it a booster, it is known as a servo over here, I will update my answer.

Comment: I hadn't thought of this but it is a very viable answer ... probably quite accurate as well.

Comment: How do you get the valve free if it's stuck open?

Comment: It would be very difficult trying to explain something like this without having the exact unit available to me.  It is probably also not something I would recommend trying to repair.  Did you install the new booster?  Have you checked it is plumbed in correctly?  Can you check any pipes on it for leaks?

Comment: I went and started the truck up and i did notice something i didn't catch the first time. When the brake pedal moves to the floor by its self after starting the truck i hear a hissing sound  like air leaking out somewhere?

Comment: The air will be getting sucked in, rather than leaking out.  I am pretty sure if you can find where the hissing noise is coming from, you will find your problem.

Comment: HandyHowie @user41048 would like you to explain what you mean in your last paragraph.  Any chance you could go into more depth?  (Maybe even a picture?)  Thanks.

Comment: @Cullub From a quich search on google for “brake servo” - https://goo.gl/images/E133Jm You can see the pipe at the top.